# Как правильно создать связи в сущностях

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Сущность описывающая машину

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // Список узлов машины
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "machine_node", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "machine_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "node_id"))
    private List<NodeMachine> nodeMachines = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Сущность описывающая деталь/узел

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node_machine")
public class NodeMachine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

На каждой машине установлено несколько деталей (список nodeMachines), и каждая деталь может быть установлена на разные машины, поэтому добавил ManyToMany.

Каждая деталь установлена на конкретной машине в определенном кол-ве.
Я хочу получить количество узлов установленных в конкретной машине, зная имя узла и машины.

Опишу более подробно, что находится в таблицах. Сразу скажу, что пример не очень удачный, просто для понимания. В таблице Machine у нас есть 100 мотоциклов M (1-100) и 100 автомобилей C (1-100).  А в таблице NodeMachine всего одна запись - колесо K1, которое подходит на все сто мотоциклов и на все сто машин. Из этого никак не определить сколько колес должно быть у каждого мотоцикла и у каждой машины. Поэтому я считаю, что должна быть третья таблица где каждой машине и мотоциклы указано количество колес. А держать в таблице 200 записей колес для мотоциклов и 400 записей для машин я считаю, что это слишком избыточно.

Для этого придется создать еще одну таблицу count_machine_node с полями

```
- machine_id
- node_id
- count
```

Но какие связи необходимо прописать в этих сущностях?

Как правильно связать эти три таблицы?

Я так понимаю, что аннотация ManyToMany создаст третю таблицу связи двух таблиц по ключам machine_id и node_id. Но как указать, чтобы в этой таблице было создано поле count?
Или hibernate так не умеет делать и все-таки придется создавать третью сущность для этого?
Например вот тут [Hibernate – Many-to-Many example – join table + extra column](https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) похожая задача решаться с помощью третьей сущности. Правда статья очень старая, может уже есть решение по проще?

Comment: Если вы собираетесь вводить 3 сущность, то отношение Many-to-Many вам не нужно. Все трисущности можно объединить через Many-to-One и One-to-Many.

Comment: Да и в начальном варианте особого смысла в ManyToMany не было - зачем запчасти "знать", в каких машинах она используется.

Comment: А если надо по запчасти вывести список машин где она может быть установлена, разве не для этого нужна аннотация ManyToMany? Или я тогда совсем не понимаю для чего еще может быть нужна аннотация ManyToMany

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не хочу вводить третью сущность, но я не пойму как этим двум сущностям указать, что есть третья таблица в которой есть поле count связанное с двумя другим таблицами.

Comment: Например вы покупаете свечи зажигания, а там список из полсотни авто на которые они подходят. А как по другому вы узнаете подходят они на ваш авто или нет, не получив этого списка.

Comment: Для того чтобы знать какие свечи подходят на авто, не нужно знать кол-во свечей, которые нужно в этих авто. Вы сами сказали, что вам нужно знать кол-во

Comment: Ну почему не нужно? Например, если свечи продаются поштучно и вы понятия не имеете сколько их на ваше авто надо. Где вы возьмете эту информацию?

Comment: из документации на автомобиль, из интернета. В общем там же, где и вы её возьмёте. Или только у вас в голове есть информации о кол-ве свечей в разных автомобилях? Ну или колёса, думаете владелец не в состоянии подсчитать кол-во колёс? И опять же я заостряю ваше внимание на ваши же слова, что вам важно знать подходит запчасть или нет, а не кол-во этих запчастей.

Comment: Да, блин директор хочет, чтобы эта позиция была. Я понимаю, что все можно найти в интернете, а вот он хочет, чтобы типа зашел  на сайт чел, который не умеет искать, а тут ему типа подсказка. Можно тут полемику развести на несколько страниц. Но есть в этом смысл? Я ясно написал в условии, что надо иметь возможность по запчасти определить на какие авто она подходит. И (не ИЛИ а И) чтобы можно было по запчасти определить кол-во этих запчастей на любой из машин куда она подходит. Причем ни то ни другое мне не важно, а просто должна быть возможность эту информацию достать из БД.

Comment: Если бы не это кол-во то и проблем бы не было у меня только с ним стопор вышел. Связать список запчастей с авто, с этим проблем нет. А вот как средствами Hibernate засунуть в эту таблицу связи еще и кол-во - я такой информации ни где не могу найти. У mkyong нашел что-то похожее, но этому решению уже 10 лет, с тех пор уже много поменялось.

Answer (score 0):

Я вам предлагаю следующий вариант решения. От таблицы "машины" мы отказываемся совсем. У нас будет таблица узлов (Node) и их наследников (ChildNode). Для понимания какого типа у нас узел вводится таблица типов узлов - Type. Она будет принимать значения: машина, свеча, колесо и т.д.

Тут нет связей Многие-ко-Многим. Только Один-ко-Многим (Многие-к-Одному).

Следует обратить внимание, что машины существуют с разными двигателями и, соответственно, не всем двигателям нужны, например, свечи. Тогда нужно будет либо создавать узел-машину с разным наименованием (хотя марка может быть одна и та же, либо делать древовидную структуру узлов. Т.е. в машину входят такие-то двигатели, в двигатели входят такие-то свечи (и только там, где нужно)

[image: Схема]

**UPD**

Если нам нужно найти все узлы входящие в машину, то в случае плоского справочника (когда у нас есть машина и все дочерние узлы цепляются только к ней), необходимо из таблицы **ChildNode** выбрать все записи с **idParentNode** выбранной машины. Если нам нужно знать только типы этих узлов, то в запросе можно сделать группировку по типу узла (`ChildNode JOIN Node (idNode -> id) GROUP BY Node.idType`), ну или же `DISTINCT` по типу узла.

Если у нас справочник иерархический, то будет сложнее. Придётся рекурсивно выбирать из всех узлов все дочерние узлы.

Как это работает на примере колёс (таблица **Node**):

- узел № 1 "Камаз" типа "машина"
- узел № 2 "Мотоцикл" типа "машина"
- узел № 3 "колесо на Камаз" типа "колесо"
- узел № 4 "комплект колес на Камаз" типа "колесо"
- узел № 5 "колесо на мотоцикл" типа "колесо"

Вы создаёте для узла № 1 дочерние (таблица **ChildNode**):

- № 3 в количестве 6
- № 4 в количестве 1

Вы создаёте для узла № 2 дочерние (таблица **ChildNode**):

- № 5 в количестве 2

Comment: А как вы получите информацию о всех узлах установленных на конкретной машине (узел у которого Type = machine)? И так как у вас поле count находится в узле, то узел получается уникальным (т.е. получаем избыточность данных). Например у узла (колесо) будут наследники мотоцикл, легковое авто и камаз. Соответственно count = 2, 4, 6, т.е. придется создавать трои объекта.

Comment: @alex, обновил сообщение. Вы ошибаетесь. Поле count находится не в узле, а в связи дочернего и родительского узла. Вы невнимательно посмотрели на диаграмму.

Comment: Тогда у вас в таблице Node не хватает ссылки на дочерний Node.
А ChildNode - это получается таблица связей. Самый главный вопрос как перенести все это в код? Как с помощью аннотаций описать эту таблицу связей?

Comment: @alex, ну научитесь вы читать. ссылка на дочерние узлы организована через таблицу **ChildNode**. Эта таблица - сущность. Описывать её нужно так же как и таблицу **Node**  или **Type**. Про тип связи я вам написал в ответе